# what's the formula of the inradius of a general simplex?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, euclidean-geometry

As the title, I just want to know whether there is a general formula for calculating the inradius of a n-simplex. Thank you!

Comment: What quantities are you assuming to be known for your $n$−simplex? Is there a formula for a triangle?

Comment: $\frac{\textrm{volume}}{n\cdot\textrm{surface-area}}$?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently not in complete generality; here is a a formula for a [hyperbolic truncated $n$-simplex](http://homeweb.unifr.ch/jacquemm/pub/docs/Inradius.pdf), and here for a [regular simplex](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00773406). There is also a formula for a triangle.